# How do employ ' ("prime") in math mode at the correct depth?

Tags: math-mode, subscripts

How does one use the `'` symbol ("apostrophe") in math mode without letting it change the depth of subscripts?

For example the following tex code:

```
\[
\int_{G^d} \varphi_{\ul,\ui} \varphi_{\ul',\ui'} \varphi_{\ul\prime,\ui\prime}  dx
\]
```

yields the following result

[image: Result]

We notice that using the apostrophe `'` looks way better than the overall result from using `\prime`, **but sadly using `'` affects the depth below the baseline at which subscripts are placed.**

How can one use `'` properly in math mode?

Difference:

[image: Difference]

Comment: Welcome! I'm not sure what you mean by “the subscripts do not have the same size”.

Comment: hey. Thanks for the answer. If you look really close you see in the screenshot that the secound $\underline{l}', \underline{i}'$ is a big bigger than the other ones. See the picture I added :)

Comment: `\prime` is a full-size glyph, and is meant to be used only in an explicit superscript, by itself.  Hence, instead of `\phi_{l\prime}`, use `\phi_{l^{\prime}}`.  (The apostrophe is equivalent to `^{\prime}` with finagling to allow multiple apostrophes to be input consecutively without triggering a "double superscript" error.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want subscripts to be on the same level, just add `\mathstrut` to them.  A strut is an invisible thin vertical rectangle used in vertical spacing.

```
\int_{G^d} \varphi_{\mathstrut l,i} \varphi_{\mathstrut l',i'} dx
```

[image]

P.S. In addition to `\mathstrut`, `\strut` also works, but @Mico suggests below, using `\mathstrut` instead of `\strut` is better in math mode.

Answer (score 6):

They're not smaller, but lowered less than the primed subscripts. Use a phantom, when you have to align subscripts.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\ul}{\underline{l}}
\newcommand{\ui}{\underline{i}}
\newcommand{\vp}{^{\vphantom{\prime}}}

\begin{document}

\[
\int_{G^d} \varphi_{\ul\vp,\ui\vp} \varphi_{\ul',\ui'}\,dx
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]